# i can't get coordinates double of firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, gps

i wanna keep the position of the db in a variable but it dont work property and when i run the application it crashed how can i solved it.

```
double latitud=0.0;
double longitud = 0.0;
latitudRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            Double value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
            latitud = value;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });
    longitudRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            Double value1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
            longitud = value1;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message and stack trace, which you can get from logcat.

Comment: We'll probably also need to see the JSON at the database location that `latitudRef` points to. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure.